# How to add META tags in Plone custom content template

Tags: seo, plone, meta-tags, custom-type

I have a Plone 4.2 customized home page template (view.pt) that is missing META tags which appear in the (main_template.pt). I've added the entire  section from main_template.pt to the same place in view.pt but this fails to add the meta tags.

What structures do I need to add to my template for the meta tags to appear on these custom template types?

Many Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: I am trying to pull in the meta tags from QuintaGroup's SEO Properties Add-In. Our custom-type template is not accessing the SEO items plus the Dublin Core items which will appear on the rest of the pages. What is the code that specifically pulls in the Dublin Core meta tags?

Comment: The solution is that the QuintaGroup SEO Properties package contains a known bug. http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/attachment/ticket/249/unat.diff identifies what changes to make in the case of a Dexterity Content Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is that the QuintaGroup SEO Properties package contains a known bug. http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/attachment/ticket/249/unat.diff identifies what changes to make in the case of a Dexterity created Content Type template.

You need to make the change to the package then add it to your site(s) and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Plone has several head slots you can use to have your template's meta tags injected into the right places in the main template. Everything you need is right here: http://developer.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/template_basics.html#head-slots

Comment: That is probably what I need. Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: I may need more explicit information about how to use this info. The examples are for implementing some fixed CSS but what I'm looking for is a way to implement the contents from SEO Properties tab (quintagroup.seoptimizer 4.2.0). What have I missed? Thanks!!